# How to set script timeout for JX browser

Tags: jxbrowser

We are using [jxbrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser) version 6.21 (latest at the time of writing).

If a script gets stuck in an endless loop the jxbrowser just freezes and remains unresponsive. I waited more than 2 minutes.

Is there any way to handle this smoothly?

Modern browsers detect this and show an overlay to the user to stop the script.

**SSCCE:** html-file with this content:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            function badLoop() {
                var nextTime = new Date().getTime();
                while (true) {
                    var now = new Date().getTime();
                    if (now > nextTime) {
                        console.log('badLoop() running: ' + now);
                        nextTime = now + 500;
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
        <input type="button" value="startLoop" onClick="badLoop()" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**Test runs with other browsers:**

- Firefox after about 15 seconds:
  [image: Firefox]
- When pressing "stop website" Firefox just stops the script, but keeps the website open and logs this in the console:
  [image: FirefoxConsole]
- Google Chrome after about 30 seconds:
  [image: GoogleChrome]
- Google Chrome (other than firefox) actually leaves the webseite after pressing leave (and shows this error):
  [image]

**Is this possible with jxbrowser? Either fully automatically or with user-confirm?**

Comment: Could you please add an SSCCE that can be used to reproduce the described behavior in JxBrowser? In addition, is it correct that you use the `Browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue()` method to launch such script?

Comment: Added SSCCE and sample screenshots from FF and Chrome. I do NOT use this execute command. See my SSCCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample that demonstrates how to intercept the corresponding `onRenderUnresponsive` event in JxBrowser and detect that the web page became unresponsive:

```
public class BrowserSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Browser browser = new Browser();
        BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(700, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        browser.addRenderListener(new RenderAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onRenderUnresponsive(RenderEvent event) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(view, "The web page is unresponsive.");
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        browser.loadHTML("<html>\n"
                + "    <body>\n"
                + "        <script>\n"
                + "            function badLoop() {\n"
                + "                var nextTime = new Date().getTime();\n"
                + "                while (true) {\n"
                + "                    var now = new Date().getTime();\n"
                + "                    if (now > nextTime) {\n"
                + "                        console.log('badLoop() running: ' + now);\n"
                + "                        nextTime = now + 500;\n"
                + "                    }\n"
                + "                }\n"
                + "            }\n"
                + "        </script>\n"
                + "        <input type=\"button\" value=\"startLoop\" onClick=\"badLoop()\" />\n"
                + "    </body>\n"
                + "</html>");
    }
}
```

See https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000091687-detecting-unresponsive-web-page